# IIS ApplicationName at runtime ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am constructing a URL at runtime in a ASP.NET MVC application. What is the best way to do this?

```
 url = string.Format("/controller/action/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}", request.Id,
                                           builds.Release, builds.Localization.Value, builds.Label, SessionId);
```

The URL is ultimately used to make an AJAX call back to a controller action. The problem is that in my deployment environment this application is not the root and therefore the URL is not valid.

{host}\url <-- this is what I have.
{host}{applicationname}\url <-- this is what I need.

So I was going to resolve the application name at runtime and use it to construct the url. How can I get just the applicationname? Is this the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include Request.ApplicationPath as the firt part of your url.

```
url = string.Format("{0}controller/action/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}", Request.ApplicationPath, request.Id,
                                           builds.Release, builds.Localization.Value, builds.Label, SessionId);
```

You may also want to take a look at the VirtualPathUtility class. Specifically

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the [URL helper Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348.aspx) method:

```
Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { 
    id = request.Id, 
    release = builds.Release, 
    localization = builds.Localization.Value, 
    label = builds.Label, 
    sessionId = SessionId 
});
```

This obviously implies that you have the correct route set (taking `id`, `release`, `localization`, `label` and `sessionId` tokens):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{release}/{localization}/{label}/{sessionId}",
    new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" }
);
```

Remark: never use string concatenations and/or string.Format when dealing with urls if you don't want to have problems with url encodings, etc...

Remark 2: An instance of the UrlHelper is available in each controller action as Url property of the controller, in each view, and in each helper.